# How to update the figure of a px.line

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to draw a chart of btc and show one hour after one hour like a slideshow (no animation or effect is needed). However I'm not able to update the figure stemming from px.line() without the browser opening a new tab. How would I do this, like remaining in the same tab and just updating the data of the line and redraw it?

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import time

df = pd.read_csv('btc.csv')

i=0
shown=False
part_df1=df.iloc[0:60]
fig = px.line(part_df1, x = 'date_x', y = 'price_y', title='btc price ..')
fig.show()  
while i<600:
    time.sleep(0.25)
    i=i+60
    part_df=df.iloc[i:i+60]
    fig = px.line(part_df, x = 'date_x', y = 'price_y', title='btc price ..')
    fig.show()
```

so something like:

```
fig.update(px.line(part_df, x = 'date_x', y = 'price_y', title='btc price ..'))
```

instead of

```
fig = px.line(part_df, x = 'date_x', y = 'price_y', title='btc price ..')
fig.show()
```

Comment: plotly doesn't support this functionality as once the figure is shown in your browser, it cannot be updated from the code you're running – however such a solution is possible in `plotly-dash` because of `callbacks` and the `dcc.Interval` object – if you're interested in such a solution, i would be happy to write up a demonstration

Comment: yes, that would be perfect. thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've put together an example `plotly-dash` app that performs a [live update](https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates) for data over a predefined period of time. Some of the important features are:

- the `dcc.Interval` object automatically triggers the `callback` function for updating the figure every interval of time (e.g. update the figure every 1 second). there's also an `n_interval` counter which will be useful for helping us keep track of the indices in the `df` we are iterating through (documentation [here](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/interval))
- the `extendData` property of `dcc.Graph` allows you to return a dictionary from your callback (and saves you the trouble of having to directly modify the data inside the figure object). (documentation [here](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/graph?_gl=1*17plnfk*_ga*MTc4OTIzMjEyMy4xNjc1NjM1NTAz*_ga_6G7EE0JNSC*MTY3NjQ5MjIzNS4yMC4xLjE2NzY0OTIzMDcuMC4wLjA.#graph-properties))

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

# df = pd.read_csv('btc.csv')

## create some random walk data
np.random.seed(42)
change = np.random.choice([-1,0,1], 600-1)

btc = [20000]
for y_change in change:
    btc_new = btc[-1] + 1000*y_change
    btc.append(btc_new)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01', periods=600),
    'btc': btc
})

part_df=df.iloc[0:60]
fig = px.line(part_df, x = 'date', y = 'btc', title='btc price')

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph', figure=fig),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=1000, # 0.25*1000, # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=1,
            max_intervals=len(df) // 60 - 1
        )
    ])
)

@app.callback(Output('live-update-graph', 'extendData'),
              [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'),
               Input('live-update-graph', 'figure')])
def extend_trace(n, fig):

    if 60*n > len(df):
        return {}
    else:
        part_df = df.iloc[60*n:60*(n+1)]

        return (dict(
            x=[part_df['date'].tolist()],
            y=[part_df['btc'].tolist()],
        ))

app.run(debug=True)
```

[image]

Update: if you don't need to the data to extend, and only want to show the new incoming data, then you can use the `figure` property of `dcc.Graph` instead of `extendData`. Then your callback would look like the following:

```
@app.callback(Output('live-update-graph', 'figure'),
              [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'),
               Input('live-update-graph', 'figure')])
def extend_trace(n, fig):

    if 60*n > len(df):
        return fig
    else:
        part_df = df.iloc[60*n:60*(n+1)]

        return (dict(
            data=[dict(
                x=part_df['date'].tolist(),
                y=part_df['btc'].tolist(),
            )]
        ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for. It just seems that it is adding new intervals instead of just replacing them with a new one.

Comment: @user3776738 i think i misunderstood your question slightly. in that case, we probably don't need to use the `extendData` property of `dcc.Graph` – i've updated my answer

Comment: Yep, that was what I needed, but it is good to know how to do the extended version. Might be useful as well in the future. THX